# Why won't napari show my image data in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, xcb, python-napari

I'm getting the following warnings in Colab after trying to use napari and I'm not too sure how to fix them:

[image: Napari warnings]

Is napari compatible with Google Colab or would it be better to use something else? I find it strange that the final warning states at the Qt platform has been found but could not be loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: napari uses Qt, and Qt needs a graphical environment to display the windows, and it seems that Google Colab does not provide it so it fails. So in conclusion napari cannot run on Google Colab

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @eyllanesc, I'll try using matplotlib instead